# Sul significato e l'origine del termine 'spirtusa'

Tags: word-meaning, regional, etymology

C'è qualcuno che sa cosa significhi 'spirtusa' in siciliano, se di siciliano trattasi, e quale sia l'origine del termine?

Ho visto scritta questa parola su questa maglietta.

[image]

Comment: Da [questa domanda](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/31/are-questions-about-dialects-on-topic) su Meta era emerso un certo consenso sul fatto che domande specifiche su dialetti diversi dall'italiano standard (a maggior ragione per sardo, siciliano e altri che sono vere lingue a sé) sono viste per lo più come fuori tema.

Comment: https://scn.wiktionary.org/wiki/spirtusari

Answer (score 7):

Ho letto tanti libri di Andrea Camilleri, che adesso capisco un po' il siciliano. ***Spirtusare*** significa *bucare, forare*.

Secondo questa [fonte](http://sites.unice.fr/site/henneboi/SVG-lirces/langues/real/dialectes/spriparato.htm), questa parola proviene dal latino *pertundere*, che significa proprio  *bucare, forare*.

Comment: Da cui anche l'italiano "pertugio" (buco)

Comment: Il participio passato di _pertundere_ è _pertusus_